# Dart: Get current value in Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, stream

I am making a Flutter App, where I use Firebase Auth and Cloud Firestore. For every user, I have a trainer document with the user uid as the document id.
When I update the data of my trainers, I want to make sure that only the document of the currently logged in user can be modified.

I have an AuthService class with the following method to get the current user:

```
Stream<FirebaseUser> get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged;
}
```

So when I want to change the trainer document in my DatabaseService class, I want to get the current value of the stream to get the user uid. I do not think that I can use StreamBuilder or Provider, as this is not a Widget Tree, but a simple Dart class. However, I do not think that I can use .listen() either, as I only want to get current Stream value, not all of them.

How do I get the current value of a Dart Stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably keep a local variable `currentUser`, listen to the Stream, and update `currentUser` everytime the Stream gives a new value. Read `currentUser`, whenever you want to get the current user.